# write Python string object to file

Tags: python, string, object

I have this block of code that reliably creates a string object. I need to write that object to a file. I can print the contents of 'data' but I can't figure out how to write it to a file as output. Also why does "with open" automatically close a_string?

```
with open (template_file, "r") as a_string:
   data=a_string.read().replace('{SERVER_NAME}', server_name).replace('{BRAND}', brand).replace('{CONTENT_PATH}', content_path).replace('{DAMPATH}', dampath).replace('{ENV}', env).replace('{CACHE_DOCROOT}', cache_docroot)
```

Comment: `a_string.write(your_string_object)` should work inside the `with` block

Comment: Do you want to write the string to the file or do you want to read the file and replace parts of the read string?

Comment: I need to read the template file into memory, make changes to it then write out the (changed) object to a new file. I do not want to edit the file "in place."

Answer (score 3):

> > I can print the contents of 'data' but I can't figure out how to write it to a file as output

Use `with open` with mode 'w' and `write` instead of `read`:

```
with open(template_file, "w") as a_file:
   a_file.write(data)
```

> > Also why does "with open" automatically close a_string?

`open` returns a `File` object, which implemented both `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods. When you enter the `with` block the `__enter__` method is called (which opens the file) and when the `with` block is exited the `__exit__` method is called (which closes the file).

You can implement the same behavior yourself:

```
class MyClass:
    def __enter__(self):
        print 'enter'
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        print 'exit'

    def a(self):
        print 'a'

with MyClass() as my_class_obj:
     my_class_obj.a()
```

The output of the above code will be:

```
'enter'
'a'
'exit'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open (template_file, "r") as a_string:
   data=a_string.read().replace('{SERVER_NAME}', server_name).replace('{BRAND}', brand).replace('{CONTENT_PATH}', content_path).replace('{DAMPATH}', dampath).replace('{ENV}', env).replace('{CACHE_DOCROOT}', cache_docroot).replace('{SLD}', sld)

filename = "{NNN}_{BRAND}_farm.any".format(BRAND=brand, NNN=nnn)
with open(filename, "w") as outstream:
    outstream.write(data)
```

Comment: I learned chaining yesterday and string formatting today.
I don't know if I should be closing the file but Imet my goal to be able to generate a config file and name it in one fell swoop.